# Cowpertwait-Metcalfe Introductory Time Series Exercise 4.8 - Derive ARIMA Model

Tags: time-series, arima

I am trying to solve Exercise 4.8 in Cowpertwait-Metcalfe: Introductory Time Series with R. (For self study, not for coursework.)

We are given a time series model
\begin{align*}
x_t & = x_{t - 1} + b_{t - 1} + w_t\\
b_{t - 1} & = 0.167 (x_{t - 1} - x_{t - 2}) + 0.833 b_{t - 2}
\end{align*}
where $w_t$ is white noise. We are asked to do some algebra to this system of equations, and derive
$$ (1 - 0.167 \mathbf{B} + 0.167 \mathbf{B}^2) (1 - \mathbf{B})x_t = w_t $$
where $\mathbf{B}$ is the backward shift (i.e., $\mathbf{B} x_t = x_{t - 1}$).

No matter how I try, I just can't get the desired equation. Here is my attempt: Put $\alpha = 0.167$, $\beta = 0.833$, $y_t = (1 - \mathbf{B}) x_t = x_t - x_{t - 1}$. Then we can rewrite the system as
\begin{align*}
y_t & = b_{t - 1} + w_t\\
b_t & = \alpha y_t + \beta b_{t - 1}
\end{align*}
or equivalently $\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
-\alpha & 1
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
y_t\\
b_t
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
b_{t - 1} + w_t\\
\beta b_{t - 1}
\end{pmatrix}$. Inverting $\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
-\alpha & 1
\end{pmatrix} $ gives me
$$\begin{pmatrix}
y_t\\
b_t
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
b_{t - 1} + w_t\\
(\alpha + \beta) b_{t - 1} + \alpha w_t
\end{pmatrix}$$
Still, this does not get me any closer to showing $(1 - \alpha \mathbf{B} + \alpha \mathbf{B}^2) y_t = w_t$. Could someone point me in the right direction? Thank you.